# Counting the number of elements having the same keys in a Python list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have the following python list of dictionaries

```
list_of_dict = [
    {'id': 0, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 0, 'AU_start_position': 0},
    {'id': 1, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 0, 'AU_start_position': 4095}, 
    {'id': 2, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 0, 'AU_start_position': 8092},
    {'id': 0, 'au_type': 3, 'sequence_id': 0, 'AU_start_position': 5678},    
    {'id': 0, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 13525}, 
    {'id': 1, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 13587}, 
    {'id': 2, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 14576},
    {'id': 0, 'au_type': 3, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 15019}, 
    {'id': 1, 'au_type': 3, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 15560}, 
    {'id': 2, 'au_type': 3, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 16004}
]
```

I have `seq_count` as the total number of different `'sequence_id'` and `num_classes` as the total number of different `'au_type'`. 
In the example above:

```
seq_count = 2
num_classes = 2
```

I need to implement a list `numid_seq_cl[seq_count][num_classes]` returning the number of different `'id'` with the same `'au_type'` and `'sequence_id'`.
In the example above,

```
numid_seq_cl[0][1] = 3
numid_seq_cl[0][3] = 1
numid_seq_cl[1][1] = 3
numid_seq_cl[1][3] = 3
```

Comment: ``"I need to implement a list ..."`` - ok, what have you tried and where/how did your code fail?

Comment: I think what you really want is a dict not a list here. A list to me makes no sense.

Comment: You are right about the fact I did not posted what I did to get the list, I should have written that I'd need hints on where to start and not just ask for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution with lists:

```
max_au = -1
max_sq = -1
# Find list limits
for item in list_of_dict:
    sq = item['sequence_id']
    max_au = max(max_au, item['au_type'])
    max_sq = max(max_sq, item['sequence_id'])

assert max_au > 0, max_sq >= 0

numid_seq_cl = [[0 for j in range(max_au + 1)] for i in range(max_sq + 1)]

# Fill list
for item in list_of_dict:
    numid_seq_cl[item['sequence_id']][item['au_type']] += 1

print(numid_seq_cl)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 3, 0, 1], [0, 3, 0, 3]]
```

However, I strongly recommend not using a list, but using a dictionary:

```py
numid_seq_cl = {}

for item in list_of_dict:
    au = item['au_type']
    sq = item['sequence_id']

    # Set default values, so dictionary items can be easily incremented
    if au not in numid_seq_cl:   # Set a default value for the first level of the dictionary
        numid_seq_cl[au] = {}
    if sq not in numid_seq_cl[au]:  # Set a default value for the second level of the dictionary
        numid_seq_cl[au][sq] = 0

    numid_seq_cl[au][sq] += 1
```

EDIT: Added list solution

Comment: Hey, your code looks good. However, I have a question to ask, how your code works. When we come to if statement, it all blurs out for me. Thanks :)

Comment: @Alok Updated the answer with comments

Comment: @tituszban Thank you for your answer. Actually I'd need a list, not a dictionary..

Comment: @user123892 Added list solution. But you really should use a dictionary.

Comment: @tituszban: the software I am implementing is based on a standard and it requires a list to hold the number of `id` per `sequence_id` and `au_type`. I will get in touch with the guys that are developing this standard and explain them the issue. 
Thank you for the solution with zeros accounting for the missing indexes.

Answer (score 1):

A meaningful result in your case would be a dict of dicts.
Use the following approach with flexible [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) object:

```
from collections import defaultdict

list_of_dicts = [
    {'id': 0, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 0, 'AU_start_position': 0},
    {'id': 1, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 0, 'AU_start_position': 4095},
    {'id': 2, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 0, 'AU_start_position': 8092},
    {'id': 0, 'au_type': 3, 'sequence_id': 0, 'AU_start_position': 5678},
    {'id': 0, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 13525},
    {'id': 1, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 13587},
    {'id': 2, 'au_type': 1, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 14576},
    {'id': 0, 'au_type': 3, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 15019},
    {'id': 1, 'au_type': 3, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 15560},
    {'id': 2, 'au_type': 3, 'sequence_id': 1, 'AU_start_position': 16004}
]

numid_seq_cl = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int))  # default structure
for d in list_of_dicts:
    numid_seq_cl[d['sequence_id']][d['au_type']] += 1

numid_seq_cl = {k: dict(v) for k, v in numid_seq_cl.items()}
print(numid_seq_cl)  # {0: {1: 3, 3: 1}, 1: {1: 3, 3: 3}}
```

And here's your expected *indexing*:

```
print(numid_seq_cl[0][1])   # 3
print(numid_seq_cl[0][3])   # 1
print(numid_seq_cl[1][1])   # 3
print(numid_seq_cl[1][3])   # 3
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, the result is correct but it is a dictionary and actually I do need a list..

Comment: @user123892, I guess you don't clearly understand the caveats. Post the expected output list structure in case if your input list have dicts with only `sequence_id = 3` and `sequence_id = 5`. Let me know after you handle that

Comment: Yes, I've got it. I was so focused on finding a solution that I did not realise I do not have subsequent indexes in both sequence_id and au_type.